# Can't import fonts in react (node-sass)

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, fonts, sass

I'm currently developing a small project for my brother who needs to realize a website (he is in an art-school).

I was planning to do it in React (good for me to practice)

I recently started to use Sass and fell in love with it, it's so much handy than regular css !

Anyway,
He gave me a font to use for his website (https://www.velvetyne.fr/fonts/le-murmure/) but I can't manage it to import it in the project. I had read so many subjects but I can't make it work.

So I found their was two solutions, one is to use import because then the font will enter in the build pipeline, and the other is to use directly the build folder. Apparently using import is the best practice.

I found this answer saying we need to put them in an assets folder (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5213#issuecomment-284783844) so this is what I did, this time I got no error message saying 'hey can't resolve blablabla' but it simply don't use the font. 
+ I can put whatever I want like '/assets/somethings/dumb' I will not get any error message.

I'll send you a picture of my tree so you can see better

https://ibb.co/KjkCNJ1

Here is my _typography.scss

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'murmure';
    src:  url('/assets/fonts/Le_Murmure-Regular_web.eot');
    src:  url('/assets/fonts/Le_Murmure-Regular_web.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('/assets/fonts/Le_Murmure-Regular_web.woff') format('woff'),
          url('/assets/fonts/Le_Murmure-Regular_web.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('/assets/fonts/Le_Murmure-Regular_web.ttf') format('truetype'),
          url('/assets/fonts/Le_Murmure-Regular_web.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

Which I import into my main.scss

```
//      ABSTRACTS
@import './abstracts/functions';
@import './abstracts/mixins';
@import './abstracts/variables';

//      BASE
@import './base/typography';
@import './base/base';
@import './base/animations';
@import './base/utilities';

//      COMPONENTS
@import './components/input.scss';

//      LAYOUTS 

//      PAGES

@import './screens/home';
```

which I import into my App.tsx

```
import '@assets/sass/main.scss';
```

Finally

I have a rule in my screens/_home.scss

```
.home {
    &__title {
        font-size: 500px;
        font-family: "murmure", serif !important;
    }
}
```

And the only thing that gets applied is the font-size 
https://ibb.co/gt2Bvdz

Does someone have an idea how to make the fonts import ?

I'm really stuck into this :/
Have the impression I just tried every relative imports I could

Comment: Can you show me the webpack config ?